# tensorflow placeholder - understanding `shape=[None,`

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to understand placeholders in tensorflow. Specifically what `shape=[None,` means in the example below.

```
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 128, 128, 3], name="X")
```

[This](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-Variables-and-Placeholders-in-tensor-flow) answer describes it as:

> You can think of a placeholder in TensorFlow as an
>   operation specifying the shape and type of data that will be fed into
>   the graph.placeholder X defines that an unspecified number of rows of shape
>   (128, 128, 3) of type float32 will be fed into the graph. a
>   Placeholder does not hold state and merely defines the type and shape
>   of the data to flow into the graph.

When it says "unspecified number of ROWS" does it really mean unspecified number of tensors of shape 128*128*3? Like you are creating a placeholder for input images for input images to a CNN?

Answer (score 19):

The first dimension represents the number of samples (images in your case). The reason why you do not want to hardcode a specific number there is to keep things flexible and allow for any number of samples. By putting `None` as the first dimension of the tensor you enable that. Consider the following 3 very common actions:

1. **Batch training**: You are going to use batches of samples of relatively small length (32, 64, ...)
2. **Train evaluation**: evaluation of perfomance over all training samples
3. **Test evaluation**: evaluation performance over all testing samples

All of these will work with a different number of samples in general. However, you do not have to worry because the `None` got you covered.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the official document of tf.TensorShape

"none" means:

> Partially-known shape: has a known number of dimensions, and an
> unknown size for one or more dimension. e.g. TensorShape([None, 256])

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/TensorShape#used-in-the-notebooks