# How to change an tensor of shape (726,) to (None,726)?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, tf.keras

I wanted to create a custom loss function that suppresses all the prediction values except the highest one to zero like this:

```
def loss_function(y_true, y_pred):
    th=[tf.math.argmax(y_pred[i]) for i in range(batch_size)]
    output=tf.zeros([batch_size,len(anchor_list)])
    y_pred_in=tf.tensor_scatter_nd_update(output,[[i,th[i]] for i in range(batch_size)],[y_pred[i,th[i]] for i in range(batch_size)])
    print(y_true,y_pred_in)
    #tf.print(y_pred_in)
    cce = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()
    loss=cce(y_true,y_pred_in)
    return loss
```

I have created and compiled the model like this:

```
#hyperparameters 
nbx=len(anchor_list)
lr=0.0001
epochs=200 
batch_size=8
reg=False

with open("dataframe.pkl","rb") as vector_file:
    vect_df=pickle.load(vector_file) 
    input_list=[np.stack(vect_df[str(i)]) for i in range(nbx) ]

#with np.printoptions(threshold=np.inf):    


#input data 
data=input_list 
label_path=glob.glob("test_image/*.pkl") 
label=lb. read_label_file(label_path)

label1=np.array([a[0] for a in label])
label_o=np.array(label1) 
input_label=np.stack(label_o)
model=nn.Merge_model("17-7-1",nbx,regress=reg)

nn.Batch(batch_size)
prediction=nn.train_eval(data,input_label,model,nbx,lr,epochs,batch_size,regress=reg)
```

The merged model part is too large to show here. However, when I run this code I get the following error:

```
[INFO]Trainig the network....
Epoch 1/200
Tensor("y_true:0", shape=(None, 726), dtype=float32) Tensor("y_pred_in:0", shape=(8, 726), dtype=float32)
58/59 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s - loss: 16.1181 - accuracy: 0.0000e+00
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-7cd9411ed839> in <module>
     42 # plot_model(model, to_file='model.png',rankdir='LR')
     43 nn.Batch(batch_size)
---> 44 prediction=nn.train_eval(data,input_label,model,nbx,lr,epochs,batch_size,regress=reg)

~\Desktop\collection\a\box\poster_Network.py in train_eval(data, label, model, nbx, lr, epochs_in, batch_size_in, regress)
    130                                                                                    mode='max', save_best_only=True) 
    131     #gw = GetWeights()
--> 132     H=model.fit(train_list,trainY,validation_data=(test_list,testY),epochs=epochs_in,batch_size=batch_size_in,callbacks=[model_checkpoint_callback])
    133 
    134     #creating check point

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1187                 _r=1):
   1188               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1189               tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
   1190               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1191                 context.async_wait()

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\traceback_utils.py in error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    151     except Exception as e:
    152       filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
--> 153       raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    154     finally:
    155       del filtered_tb

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     56   try:
     57     ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 58     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     59                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     60   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

InvalidArgumentError:  required broadcastable shapes
     [[node gradients/categorical_crossentropy/mul_grad/Mul_1
 (defined at C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\optimizer_v2\optimizer_v2.py:466)
]] [Op:__inference_train_function_183844]

Errors may have originated from an input operation.
Input Source operations connected to node gradients/categorical_crossentropy/mul_grad/Mul_1:
In[0] gradients/categorical_crossentropy/mul_grad/Shape/y_true: 
In[1] gradients/categorical_crossentropy/Sum_1_grad/Tile:

Operation defined at: (most recent call last)
>>>   File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
>>>     return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
>>> 
>>>   File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
>>>     exec(code, run_globals)
>>> 
>>>   File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py", line 16, in <module>
>>>     app.launch_new_instance()
>>> 
>>>   File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 845, in launch_instance
>>>     app.start()
>>> 
>>>   File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 612, in start
>>>     self.io_loop.start()
>>> 
>>>   File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\platform\asyncio.py", line 199, in start
>>>     self.asyncio_loop.run_forever()
>>> 
>>>   File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 570, in run_forever
>>>     self._run_once()
>>> 
>>>   File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 1859, in _run_once
>>>     handle._run()
>>> 
>>>   File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 81, in _run
>>>     self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
>>> 
>>>   File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 688, in <lambda>
>>>     lambda f: self._run_callback(functools.partial(callback, future))
>>> 
>>>   File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 741, in _run_callback
>>>     ret = callback()
>>> 
>>>   File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 814, in inner
>>>     self.ctx_run(self.run)
>>> 
>>>   File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 775, in run
>>>     yielded = self.gen.send(value)
>>> 
>>>   File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 365, in process_one
>>>     yield gen.maybe_future(dispatch(*args))
>>> 
>>>   File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 234, in wrapper
>>>     yielded = ctx_run(next, result)
>>> 
>>>   File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 268, in dispatch_shell
>>>     yield gen.maybe_future(handler(stream, idents, msg))
>>> 
>>>   File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 234, in wrapper
>>>     yielded = ctx_run(next, result)
>>> 
>>>   File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 543, in execute_request
>>>     self.do_execute(
>>> 
>>>   File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 234, in wrapper
>>>     yielded = ctx_run(next, result)
>>> 
>>>   File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\ipkernel.py", line 306, in do_execute
>>>     res = shell.run_cell(code, store_history=store_history, silent=silent)
>>> 
>>>   File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\zmqshell.py", line 536, in run_cell
>>>     return super(ZMQInteractiveShell, self).run_cell(*args, **kwargs)
>>> 
>>>   File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2894, in run_cell
>>>     result = self._run_cell(
>>> 
>>>   File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2940, in _run_cell
>>>     return runner(coro)
>>> 
>>>   File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\async_helpers.py", line 68, in _pseudo_sync_runner
>>>     coro.send(None)
>>> 
>>>   File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3165, in run_cell_async
>>>     has_raised = await self.run_ast_nodes(code_ast.body, cell_name,
>>> 
>>>   File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3357, in run_ast_nodes
>>>     if (await self.run_code(code, result,  async_=asy)):
>>> 
>>>   File "C:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3437, in run_code
>>>     exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
>>> 
>>>   File "<ipython-input-1-7cd9411ed839>", line 44, in <module>
>>>     prediction=nn.train_eval(data,input_label,model,nbx,lr,epochs,batch_size,regress=reg)
>>> 
>>>   File "C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\collection\a\box\poster_Network.py", line 132, in train_eval
>>>     H=model.fit(train_list,trainY,validation_data=(test_list,testY),epochs=epochs_in,batch_size=batch_size_in,callbacks=[model_checkpoint_callback])
>>> 
>>>   File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1189, in fit
>>>     tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
>>> 
>>>   File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 859, in train_function
>>>     return step_function(self, iterator)
>>> 
>>>   File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 849, in step_function
>>>     outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
>>> 
>>>   File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 842, in run_step
>>>     outputs = model.train_step(data)
>>> 
>>>   File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 803, in train_step
>>>     self.optimizer.minimize(loss, self.trainable_variables, tape=tape)
>>> 
>>>   File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\optimizer_v2\optimizer_v2.py", line 532, in minimize
>>>     grads_and_vars = self._compute_gradients(
>>> 
>>>   File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\optimizer_v2\optimizer_v2.py", line 584, in _compute_gradients
>>>     grads_and_vars = self._get_gradients(tape, loss, var_list, grad_loss)
>>> 
>>>   File "C:\Users\DELL\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\optimizer_v2\optimizer_v2.py", line 466, in _get_gradients
>>>     grads = tape.gradient(loss, var_list, grad_loss)
>>> 

Function call stack:
train_function -> __backward_loss_function_91131
```

I guess the problem arises from shape mismatch between these two:

```
Tensor("y_true:0", shape=(None, 726), dtype=float32) Tensor("y_pred_in:0", shape=(8, 726), dtype=float32)
```

However, I don't know how to create a tensor shape shape=(None, 726). How do I solve this problem?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The `None` is a [placeholder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51366871/tensorflow-placeholder-understanding-shape-none) for an arbitrary positive integer. IMO `(None, 726)` should work with `(8, 726)`.

Comment: It does work as you can see training does go on for some batches. However, throws an Invalid error argument error at some point. Why is this happening?@André